# How to center align and set bold a text in itext7

Tags: c#, reactjs, pdf, itext, itext7

I am new to using itext for generating a pdf. I had a problem, I have added itext7 in my references

to add a pdf with values. I wanted to center align and set bold a text field in my pdf. I have looked at various examples. However,.SetBold and chunk shows error in visual studio.

This is the function which I am calling for the pdf.

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("GetCoilWiseReport")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetCoilWiseReport(string jwt, string fixture="", string 
         type="", string ID= "",
         string delivery = "", string invoice = "", string wagon = "", string location = "", 
          string ICHP= "",string remarks="",string date="")
        {
            if (!Common.VerificationToken.VerifyJWToken(jwt))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var doc_date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/");
            var Type1 = type;
            var id1 = ID;
            var delivery1 = delivery;
            var invoice1= invoice;
            var wagon1 = wagon;
            var location1 = location;
            var ICHP1 = ICHP;
            var remarks1 = remarks;
            var date1 = date;


            string pdfDocument = @"D:\Annexure_One IT.pdf";//Utilities.ISOP_DOCS_FOLDER + 
             "MasterDocs\\SupplierDespatchATP.pdf";

            

            var dateLine = "Date:" + doc_date ;
            var coilDetails = "                                          COIL Details: " + ID;
            

            

            var firstRow = "Type : " + type +"                   ID:"+ID+ "                    Delivery No:"+delivery;
            var secondRow = "Invoice No.:" + invoice+"                 Wagon No:"+wagon+"            Location:"+location;
            var thirdRow = "ICHP : " + ICHP + "                            Remarks:" + remarks;
            


            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfDocument));
        
            //Add new page
            PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;
            PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage(ps);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            iText.Layout.Document iDoc = new iText.Layout.Document(pdf, ps);
            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
            PdfFont fontBold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.COURIER_BOLD);
            IList<String> text = new List<String>();
            
            text.Add("");
            text.Add(dateLine);
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add(coilDetails);
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add(firstRow);
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add(secondRow);
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add(thirdRow);
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("");
            text.Add("signature");
            ;

            foreach (String s in text)
            {
                //Add text and move to the next line
                //canvas.NewlineShowText(s);
                if (s == "signature")
                {
                    List<string> coilURL = new List<string>();
                    List<string> coilView = new List<string>();


                    string connectionstring = Utilities.SQL_DB1;// our SQL DB connection
                    SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    string query = "Select CCD_IMAGE_URL,CCD_VIEW_DESC from T_CQL_COIL_DESC 
                   where CCD_COIL_ID = '" + ID + "'";

                    //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn1);
                    conn1.Open();




                    // create data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable


                    da.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; (i < dt.Rows.Count); i++)
                        {
                            coilURL.Add(imgurl + dt.Rows[i]["CCD_IMAGE_URL"].ToString());
                            coilView.Add(dt.Rows[i]["CCD_VIEW_DESC"].ToString());

                            var view = "View:"+coilView[i];
                            var sig = coilURL[i];

                            iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p1 = new 
                             iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().Add(view);
                            //p.SetMaxHeight(20);
                            iDoc.Add(p1);

                            iText.Layout.Element.Image sigImage = new 
                            iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(sig));
                            sigImage.SetAutoScale(true);
                            
                            iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p = new 
                            iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().Add(sigImage);
                            //p.SetMaxHeight(20);
                            iDoc.Add(p);

                        }
                    }

                    


                    conn1.Close();
                    da.Dispose();
                }
               
                else
                {
                    iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph para = new 
                   iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph(s);
                    para.SetFont(font);
                    para.SetFontSize(9);
                    iDoc.Add(para);
                }
            }
            //iDoc.Close();

            //Close document

            iDoc.Close();
            // Add Paragraph to document



            pdf.Close();



            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(pdfDocument, 
             FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            //httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application / vnd.openxmlformats - 
            officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Coil_Detail" + 
             fixture + "_" + ID + "_" + ".pdf";
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
```

I am trying to make CoilDetails bold and center alligned. How do I do that in the current context. Please help

Comment: *"I am trying to make CoilDetails bold and center alligned. How do I do that in the current context."* - Well, first of all your current context, your architecture is designed *not* to have any text line specially styled because all of them are held in a mere string list. Of course, if it's only this one line that needs special treatment, you can remember its list position in a variable and later, when you iterate over the list, check if you are at that position. Or you can prefix that string with a marker to check for. Or can have a parallel structure holding such information. Or ...

Answer (score 3):

Use `p.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);` for aligning it in center and for setting it to bold after add try using .SetBold() or .SetFont(bold)

Comment: Hi can you add the code for the current context. I mentioned that .set bold and p.set Text alignment gives error in visual studio in the current context

Answer (score 1):

I do a few scripts w/ itext7 using linqpad.net in c#
but I've no issues to convert to visual studio.
here's a line in C#

p = new Paragraph(targetText).SetFontSize(12).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED).SetFontColor(new DeviceRgb(0, 153, 0)).SetBold();

Comment: is the same answer pretty much as Anuj, but is shows how to stack the 2+ commands for the same "p"; I'm not trying to get kudos out from Anuj.